# Can I disable the 'thymeleaf' report from the karate log

Tags: karate

Is there any way to enable and disable the thymeleaf report from the logs? I couldn't find any config flag to do, so is there any other way to switch it on/off?

Answer (score 4):

This can happen when your project has a bunch of dependencies and something in your "test-classpath" has configured the logger before Karate, or the `logback-test.xml` was not found on the classpath.

So start here first: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#logging

When you mix Karate with Spring, Quarkus or Micronaut, Graal or logging dependencies can cause conflicts. Refer to the [integration examples](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/README.md#integrations) for samples and solutions. Using the [karate "fat jar"](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md#using-the-shaded-jar) can avoid dependency conflicts in some cases.

Or if you are using some combination of dependencies or building a JAR on your own (which we don't support, you have to figure this out on your own).

In that case, this thread may give you some ideas: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1694

Finally, if you insist that this is some issue with Karate - please follow this process so that we can fix it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I put the debugger on INFO and that thymeleaf stuff is still being show. I don't think that is showing something relevant to tests and common users.

Comment: @italktothewind I have nothing to add to my answer

Comment: I'm using logback-test.xml (a different file from the logback.xml of the app) and there is no way to turn off the thymeleaf stuff. It is a bit annoying that almost all the log is related to a template framework that all the Karate users except from you don't care about, instead of just displaying the tests info. So probably there are things to add to your answer :)

Comment: @italktothewind no there aren't

Comment: <logger name="karate.org.thymeleaf" level="OFF"/> did the trick. I was using org.thymeleaf. Hope this can help other users.

Comment: In my case, the logback file was named `logback-spring.xml`, so the logger in there was ignored in favor of some karate-internal logback file (`logback-fatjar.xml`, perhaps?) per the issue linked in the answer, and so the `karate.org.thymeleaf` logger was always at DEBUG level regardless of what I set it to in my `logback-spring.xml`. I had to rename the file to `logback.xml` for my logger configuration to be picked up, which was easy enough since it didn't have any spring profile stuff.

Comment: @italktothewind maybe put your comment as an answer, as it did help me to fix the same issue.

Comment: @RobertvanderSpek thanks I edited my answer to include this info