# Logs spammed with thymeleaf debug logs whenever I'm running a simple karate feature

Tags: java, thymeleaf, karate

Has anyone else seen this when they've written and run their karate test? And if you have, how do I clean it up? I am using IntelliJ as my IDE.

```
13:51:07.900 [main] DEBUG karate.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine - [THYMELEAF] 
INITIALIZING TEMPLATE ENGINE
13:51:08.113 [main] DEBUG karate.org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG - Initializing 
Thymeleaf Template engine configuration...
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURATION:
[THYMELEAF] * Thymeleaf version: 3.0.12.RELEASE (built 2020-12-21T00:26:28+0000)
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Manager implementation: 
karate.org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers:
[THYMELEAF]     * [0] com.intuit.karate.template.ResourceHtmlTemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers:
[THYMELEAF]     * karate.org.thymeleaf.messageresolver.StandardMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Link builders:
[THYMELEAF]     * karate.org.thymeleaf.linkbuilder.StandardLinkBuilder
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [1 of 2]: Standard 
(com.intuit.karate.template.KarateStandardDialect)
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF]     * Processors for Template Mode: HTML
```

...

Edit: I tried adding the log-back file and the configure in the document, I believe the configure made it so I could see the calls in the logs but didn't clean up the spam entirely. I am wondering if the scope of the configure function applies to all of the scenarios if it is put at the top of the script, below the Feature: title.
That's where I have it now, as putting it in scenarios seemed to make the script interpret it as a String.

Comment: Please see this answer (and contribute code to Karate if needed): https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025455/143475

Comment: We are at least 3 Karate users with this issue Thomas haha