# Karate reports stopped showing server response when I upgraded version

Tags: karate

In the previous versions of Karate (before upgrading to 1.3.1) when I had this in the reports:

[image]

the "When method post" was clickable and you could see the server response. This was extremely useful for debugging (and to use tests as living documentation as BDD states), but now it is not clickable anymore.

Is there some way to have it back without downgrading to previous version of karate?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hours later I realized the cause of the problem. I have to tell that Karate's reports implementation is a bit weird because it takes the reports input *directly* from the logs so it depends on your logs configuration.

In one of the latest updates of Karate its package changed from `karate.org` to `intuit.karate`, so my log configuration in `logback-test.xml` got outdated because it was written in terms of `karate.org`.

Why was I mentioning `karate.org` in my logs? Because I have to set Karate logs to be at `DEBUG` level so I can see them, otherwise they will be lost because real systems default log level is `INFO`. If those logs are required for the reporting tool maybe Karate should set them at `INFO` level.

Note that Thymeleaf package also changed from `karate.thymeleaf` to `org.thymeleaf` because probably you will also want to disable it in a real system ([Can I disable the 'thymeleaf' report from the karate log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69024586/can-i-disable-the-thymeleaf-report-from-the-karate-log)).

PD: I love the tool, but I don't think that downvoting questions or understimate this issues will help real users.

Answer (score 0):

When you mix some dependencies with Karate it can affect the logging system. If logs are not "captured" by Karate correctly, you will have this problem.

Refer to [this example and documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-examples/blob/main/database/README.md#using-the-shaded-jar) for possible solutions

If you use the quickstart or [github template](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate-template), you will see that you won't have this problem. So for anyone to help, please follow [this process](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue).