# Unable to see Print statement values in Reporting

Tags: karate

I have run a sample POST API test and on opening the karate-reports, do not see print statement logs anything i.e. it does not come up as a link to see possible print values.

## Note: There is no log file

## Feature File

Feature: POST API CALL

```
    Background: 
    
* def bod = 
"""
{
"name": "morpheus",
"job": "leader"
}
"""

Scenario: Create Users

Given url 'https://reqres.in/api/users'
And request bod
When method POST
Then status 201
And print response
```

==================================================

print values logging properly.
[image]

Comment: refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76887529/143475

Comment: it did not help either. Same code was working last week and it has suddenly stopped showing print values.  Very hard to cope with Karate library :( @PeterThomas

Comment: as an open source project, karate depends on contributions. if you are able to help others replicate the issue, it will certainly be fixed