Why the request details is not showing up anymore in the Karate report?
in the karate report, I want to see the request details and response details under the method line, but now I cannot see it any more. Do any one know how to make it available?
in previous report, I can expand the request method line and see the request details :

in current report I cannot expand the request method line and see the request details:


please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76887529/143475

@PeterThomas Shouldn't then this be closed as a dupe?
